# discord.py Sqlite3 remove () from select

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

Sorry for the weird question but I don't know how to word it. But I'm making an economy system for my bot. I want to make a command `>balance` that will show the user's wallet and bank. From their guild_id and user_id since the user could be in more than one server with the bot.

```py
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM economy WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        await ctx.send("Umm it seems that you do not have an account. You can open an account by typing `>open_account`.")
    elif result is not None:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT wallet FROM economy WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {ctx.author.id}")
        wallet = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT bank FROM economy WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {ctx.author.id}")
        bank = cursor.fetchone()
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome to the Bank of Furry!!", description="{}'s balance:".format(ctx.author.name), color=0xe20303)
        embed.add_field(name="Wallet Balance: ", value=wallet, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Bank Balance: ", value=bank, inline=True)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    db.close()
    cursor.close()
```

When it prints out the embed it has wallet as ('0',) and bank as ('0',). I want to know how to get rid of the ('',).

*NOTE* I'm learning sqlite3 as I code my bot. So if you have any good sqlite3 docs on this I'd love to read them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, unrelated to your question, but avoid using f-strings for SQL queries. Using f-strings (or equivalent) is a common cause of security problems, so it's best to avoid getting into the habit. Instead, always use placeholders and pass the values in as a separate argument:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT wallet FROM economy WHERE guild_id = ? AND user_id = ?",
               (ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id))
```

As for the question itself, `fetchone()` returns a tuple of all the column(s) you've selected, even if there's only one; to unpack it, you can use something like:

```
wallet, = cursor.fetchone()
```

Note that `.fetchone()` might return `None` when there are no results, so you might need to separate it into two statements:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is None:
    ... handle the situation ...
wallet, = row
```

If you want more than one column, as here, you can retrieve them both with the same SELECT statement, so the next version of the code would be:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT wallet, bank FROM economy WHERE guild_id = ? AND user_id = ?",
               (ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is None:
    ... handle the situation ...
wallet, bank = row
```